# How to separate periods and copy lines in a file using sas or linux?

Tags: linux, sas

My original file is divided by time periods like this:

```
Period                   P1   P2   P3   P4   P5   P6 P7
03/01/2013 to 06/01/2013 31.0 16.5 28.7 18.1 23.4 16 12.0   
07/01/2013 to 09/01/2013 31.0 18.0 29.3 19.2 24.3 13 3.6
```

However, the file has many rows and I need those files remain like that:

```
Period     P1   P2   P3   P4   P5   P6  P7  
03/01/2013 31.0 16.5 28.7 18.1 23.4 16  12.0 
04/01/2013 31.0 16.5 28.7 18.1 23.4 16  12.0 
05/01/2013 31.0 16.5 28.7 18.1 23.4 16  12.0 
06/01/2013 31.0 16.5 28.7 18.1 23.4 16  12.0 
07/01/2013 31.0 18.0 29.3 19.2 24.3 13  3.6  
08/01/2013 31.0 18.0 29.3 19.2 24.3 13  3.6  
09/01/2013 31.0 18.0 29.3 19.2 24.3 13  3.6
```

Does anyone know how do it in a practical way using sas or linux?

Comment: Oops, You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Please update your Q with your best attempt to solve your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a DO loop.  You can use the `INTCK()` function to know how many iterations and the `INTNX()` function to calculate the new date values.

Here is you sample data.

```
data have;
  length Start Stop P1-P7 8;
  informat Start Stop mmddyy.;
  format Start Stop yymmdd10.;
  input start stop p1-p7;
cards;
03/01/2013 06/01/2013 31.0 16.5 28.7 18.1 23.4 16 12.0
07/01/2013 09/01/2013 31.0 18.0 29.3 19.2 24.3 13 3.6
;;;;
```

Now write a new data step to expand the number of rows.

```
data want;
 format period yymmdd10.;
 set have ;
 do offset=0 to intck('month',start,stop);
   period = intnx('month',start,offset);
   output;
 end;
run;
```

[image: Proc Print;]

Comment: If the source data's dates are in DDMMYY format, rather than MMDDYY, then it's simply a case of iterating from `Start` to `Stop` as the intervals are in days rather than months.